# Error while installing two similar Unity apps on a device

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I wrote an android app. It works correctly (install and run), but when I change the app bundle identifier, keystore, name of app and name of the company and after that and trying to install the "new app", my device says that the app can't be installed.

But if I delete the old app it's okay to install the new one. Why?

Comment: Show a picture of where you change all those settings.

Answer (score 1):

An android device can only have 1 installation of 1 package id.

> Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store. If you want to upload a new version of your app, the application ID (and the certificate you sign it with) must be the same as the original APK—if you change the application ID, Google Play Store treats the APK as a completely different app. So once you publish your app, you should never change the application ID

Answer (score 0):

So, the really problem was with Facebook SDK, which i used in my applications. If you will try to install new app with same Facebook SDK ID you will get error.